# angularjs, display a variable containing '{{' '}}'

Tags: angularjs

I got a variable in my angularjs scope like this:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.myvar = "{{'i want to translate this' |translate}}" + "{{' and this' |translate}}" + " but not this" ;
}
```

The translate is a custom filter which translates to french.

In the html:

```
{{myvar}}
```

I want to display "myvar" in the html but it displays the '{{' & '}}'.
I made a jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/fchocts2/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your jsfiddle code:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  {{myvar}}
</div>
```

You've not used `ng-app="myApp"` directive anywhere. So angular know that which part of the HTML it need to bootstrap as angular app.

Another thing, you must avoid using `global` functions as controllers. Instead use

```
angular.module("myApp", [])
  .controller("MyCtrl", MyCtrl);
```

Still you can't have

```
{{'i want to translate this' |translate}}" + "{{' and this' |translate}}
```

in your controller. instead you must use `$filter` and do the filtering in controller and just return the string.

```
$scope.myVar = $filer("translate")("i want to translate this") + $filer("translate")(" and this");
```

Inject `$filter` to your controller.

Comment: the jsfiddle was forked from an empty template. i don't use global var like this but thank's to advice me. 
I will try your approche of filtering the string before concatening them in the controller.

Comment: Also you're using angular 1.0 which is too old. You must be using angular 1.3+

Comment: I use AngularJS v1.2.26 version. the jsfiddle was juste an example.

Comment: I try your advice. It work but now fully. 
In the UI i get a button to change the current site langage. so when the user change the langage the 'translate' filter translate all the data where i put it ( {{'foo'|translate}} ). This don't work.

Comment: but if I change the langage, then I make an action who recall the controller and rebuild 'myvar' it work

Comment: Either you must set a $watch to detect changes when translate button is pressed else $emit an event and listen to it in controller and upadte the value and make it work. Because currently we've used $filter in controller and it will run only once. that's why subsequent changes are not reflecting when you change the language. Else have multiple variables and do it in UI using {{"foo" | translate}}

Comment: ok thank you for the advice and time. i will read about $emit because i never use it. The translate plugin is this one : https://angular-translate.github.io/  and it have it's own controller.

Answer (score 1):

So, to start I have added some code to your jsfiddle and got it working. It renders your `myvar`.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['controllers']);
var controllers = angular.module('controllers', []);
controllers.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.myvar = "{{'i want to translate this' |translate}}" + "{{' and this' |translate}}" ;
}]);
```

Also see [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vscn7703/).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @piet.t Is this a link-only answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can find a "working" fiddle based on the good advice from @mohamedrias [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mattdionis/s98Ldua6/). By "working" I mean `ng-app` is properly declared in the html and your bindings are working. I agree with the advice already shared. Apply your filter logic within the controller. Then you could set the result to something like `vm.myTranslatedVar` and bind to that in your html with {{ vm.myTranslatedVar }}. `vm` simply stands for "view model" and sets your controller's scope rather than using `$scope`.

Comment: the filter approach work but not fully. the var is more 'myVarToTranslate' because the user can change the langage on the UI and the var should be translated also